# Double integral $\iint \cos(x - \ln x) dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm doing a double integral $$\iint_D \cos(x-\ln x)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$ where $$D=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\left|\frac{1}{e} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{y},1 \leq y \leq e\right.\right\}$$

I know that I have to substitute $x$ and $y$ for $u$ and $v$, and then use Jacobian to solve the integral.

I tried several values for $u$ and $v$ but still could not solve it. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_1^e\int_{1\over e}^{1\over y} \cos(x-\ln x) dxdy{=\int_{1\over e}^1\int_{1}^{1\over x} \cos(x-\ln x) dydx\\=\int_{1\over e}^1\left({1\over x}-1\right) \cos(x-\ln x) dx\\=-\sin(x-\ln x)\Bigg|_{1\over e}^{1}\\=\sin\left({1\over e}+1\right)-\sin 1\\\approx0.824206452}$$